# How to get parent category name form child category id wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have child category id in wordpress and i want to get parent category name for the same.i just want to fetch the parent category name only...

Answer (score 1):

You can use this kind of function :

```
function get_category_parent($child_id, $link=false, $nicename=false){
    $return = '';
    $parent = &get_category($child_id);
    if(is_wp_error($parent)) return $parent;

    if($nicename){
        $name = $parent->slug;
    }else{
        $name = $parent->cat_name;
    }

    if($link){
        $return .= '<a href="'.get_category_link($parent->term_id).'">'.$name.'</a>';
    }else{
        $return .= $name;
    }
    return $return;
}
```